# Chrome is "glitching", on my Mac, is this a known issue?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macbook-pro

Ok, so on my MacBook Pro I'm seeing some weird stuff when using Chrome. Occasionally, the screen will momentarily get messed up (see pic). Usually this happens for less than 1 second but one time it froze like that long enough for me to get the screen shot shown.

- Only seems to happen when using Chrome (Version 35.0.1916.114).
- OSX 10.9.3
- Happens on both primary monitor and when attached to secondary
  display
- Does not seem to happen to other windows being shown on same
  screen

Is this a known issue? Possible causes?

[image: chrome screen with shifted pixels]

Comment: I [can confirm](http://files.sven.bmonkeys.net/images/chromeglitch_20140607_173938.png) but it's pretty rare and usually affects only parts of the page... (same chrome, OS X 10.8.5)

Comment: I can also confirm this. It started about a week ago. recent update maybe?.. its really starting to annoy me.

Comment: I had/have the same problem, with Chrome versions up to 39.0.2171.95 and on Mavericks and Yosemite. It started with regular glitches like that. Later the screen got messed up and it froze, then the whole system crashed and could not be restarted. Diagnosis revealed corrupt RAM. I replaced it, just to find myself in the same situation a week later, with a not booting MBP and a broken logic board.

Comment: Disabling the hardware acceleration worked for me in Chrome v49.x on Snow Leopard 10.6.3. I've experienced the problem on my newer MacBooks running 10.7.5 (also with Chrome v49.x) but I haven't yet tried disabling hardware acceleration on those. It's a shame the Chrome development team never bothered fixing this bug. I daily experience it on my two MacBooks (Mid 2007 and Early 2008) and my brother on his Early 2008 MacBook.

Answer (score 4):

It's a known issue - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359108

There is a workaround listed in comment #42 - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359108#c42

They're still working on a better fix.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (May 2021 !) - I had this problem. Disabling hardware acceleration worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chorme settings, then **Advanced -> System**, and uncheck **Use hardware acceleration when available**. Then restart Chrome.

Shortcut: chrome://settings/system

This also removes the ability to change video background in Hangout meetings, if you were into that.